# Lua in iOS Objective C - path for Require

Tags: ios, objective-c, lua, require

I'm using lua for scripting in my iOS app. I'm trying to do the simple thing of adding another lua file with 'require'

My Lua files are contained within my project in XCode in the following directory:

```
Classes/Lua_Code/main.lua
Classes/Lua_Code/luaBase.lua
```

main.lua is trying to require luaBase.lua as follows -

```
require('luaBase')
```

But it never seems to find the file, even though it's in the same folder as main.lua.

I get the following errors in the log

```
no field package.preload['luaBase']     no file
'./luaBase.lua'     no file
'/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/luaBase.lua'  no file
'/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/luaBase/init.lua'     no file
'/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/luaBase.lua'    no file
'/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/luaBase/init.lua'   no file
'./function/luaBase.lua'    no file './luaBase.so'  no file
'/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/luaBase.so'     no file
'/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
```

I've tried every other suggestion here, and nothing works..

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you do `print( os.execute'pwd' )`?

Comment: Then that is the directory lua assumes you to be in.

Comment: How can I change it to the app bundle path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out -

In Objective-C - I do the following:  (self runLua: is a method that runs the text in the NSString as a lua command)

```
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
[self runLua:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"appPath = '%@/?.lua'",bundlePath]];
```

Then in Lua - I do the following:

```
package.path = appPath
require('test')
```

And finally - Lua knows where to find the files!